# driver.findElement can not find xpath with /parent

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have this code:

```
WebElement element = (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'skupiny "+skupina+"')]/parent::div/descendant::input")));
```

With this the element can not be found. Via DevTool is visible.

When I use:

```
WebElement element = (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'skupiny "+skupina+"')]"));
```

than it works fine.
Can be there some problem with finding element with "/parent or /descendant"?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a delay or using WebDriverWait to ensure the parent and descendant elements are available before attempting to find them. Also, confirm that the 'input' element is not within an iframe, as this can affect element visibility.